# Yii2 Default Pagination

Tags: pagination, yii2

How to change or style the default Pagination of YII2

[image]

I have added some css code to custom.css file,but nothing changed

```
<style>
    .pagination li {
       padding: 15px !important;
       background-color: #2a3140 !important;
       border: 1px solid wheat !important;
    }
   .pagination {
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
      padding: 18px !important;
      float: right !important;
   }

</style>
```

Comment: you have to update `.pagination > .active > a, .pagination > .active > span, .pagination > .active > a:hover, .pagination > .active > span:hover, .pagination > .active > a:focus, .pagination > .active > span:focus` and `.pagination > li > a, .pagination > li > span` to change style , and the image you posted does not look like the default pagination style for yii2, make sure your css is loading and not thorwing 404